# Error with eclipse: The local variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, eclipse

So I made some simple code in Java:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Book {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String title;
        String author;
        String pages;
        Scanner scan;
        String input = scan.nextLine();

        // Book #1
        // =1=

        Book anothermedium = new Book();


}}
```

On line 10 I get the error:

```
The local variable scan may not have been initialized
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: *"Any way to fix this"* Obviously not  by initializing it ...

Comment: In the future -- search on the error message, as this type of question gets asked daily. Also as an aside, this is not an "Eclipse" error and has nothing to do with Eclipse. It's a Java error, pure and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Don't just *declare* `scan`, *initialize* it too. Change

```
Scanner scan;
```

to something like

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```